# How to get Windows data back

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

I reinstalled Ubuntu few months ago. By accident I chose to install Ubuntu without Windows (I had dual boot operating systems before that).

This is a disaster! I lost all my data in Windows and lost the operating system as well.

Do you know if I can recover my operating system? Bring Windows back to the laptop, or at least recover those data files in Windows?

Comment: Have you been using the computer for the last several "months"?

Comment: Yes, there is a chance that files have been permanently overwritten if you're used it a lot. It depends on many things, such as how large your disk is, etc. Look at my answer though. Don't give up. I've had success in situations when I thought it would be impossible to retrieve anything.

Comment: yes. i used everyday! i didn't notice i remove windows until these days. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get Windows back as a functional system. Or at least, it's too unlikely to even attempt. However, you have good chances of finding your files. You might want to have a look at the `testdisk` package for a utility called photorec. It's very good and not too difficult to use, although you should read up before using it.